# Save records in rows or columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, database-performance

I have to save three document types in a table. number of document types is fixed and will not change. there is more than 1 million records and in the future it can be more than 100 millions. for this purpose performance is so important in my program. I don't know which way can improve the database performance. row-based or column based?

Row-Based:

```
CREATE TABLE [Person].[Document]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Document] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [DocType] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

Column-based:

```
CREATE TABLE [Person].[Document]
(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Document_Page1] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [Document_Page2] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [Document_Page3] [varbinary](max) NULL,
)
```

Comment: How many document pages do you expect to have?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen three document pages.

Comment: Do you expect to have indices on the `[Document]` and `[DocType]` columns in the row-based schema?

Comment: If you can have maximum of 3 pages then go with column based approach which will reduce the row count and will be easy to manipulate the data

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I expect indices on [PersonId] and [DocType] columns

Comment: Then maybe @ZoharPeled 's solution is correct, assuming you have those indices set up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please read my comment for ZoharPeled . flexibility is not important to me.

Comment: what would be your data like is doc1 or 2 or 3 can contain NULLs,
hows your quires will be

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma yes, but not always. rarely it can be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normalized (or as you called it - row based) solution is more flexible.
It allows you to change the number of documents saved for each person without changing the database structure, and usually is the preferred solution.
A million rows is a small table for SQL server.
I've seen database tables with 50 million rows that performs very well.
It's a question of correct indexing.

I do suggest that if you want better performance use an int identity column for your primary key instead of a uniqueidentifier, since it's very light weight and much easier for the database to index because it's not randomly ordered to begin with.

I would go with the normalized solution.

Comment: tnx for your answer, but in this project, speed and performance are more important than flexibility. records can grow fast and can be more than 100 millions records in next years. number of document types is fixed and will not change.

Comment: performance depends on queries. if most of your queries are "give me all the documents of person x", then it really doesn't matter if you choose "row based" or "column based". in fact, I'm not so sure I can think of a query that will clearly out perform on one design over the other (that is, if you have properly indexed the table).

Comment: Each document can only have a max of 3 pages by your own admission.  So you are looking at a factor of 3 difference in table size.  Will this be a deal breaker for you?

Comment: I disaggree with the int identity column instead of uniqueidentifier, because it will get harder to manage an integer key if you have 100million records on a table. Uniqueidentifier is the best way to identify a row in giant tables. And Column-based storage is a good solution if you will select data using PersonId frequently.

Comment: @Helio: [int data type in sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) is stored on 4 bytes and can hold values between -2^31 to 2^31-1. this means that if you start your identity with (1,1) you can have `2,147,483,647` records in your table before you run out of int values. that's way more then a 100 million. [uniqueidentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) is stored on 16 bytes and has no clear benefit over int. when properly indexed, I don't think there will be much difference between returning 3 records per person or 1 record.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Its not about the capacity of integer column its about the performance. It is hard to generate 100millionth row's identity if you use integer value, because it is not randomly generated, it has to be calculated over the table. If you have a fast growing table it wont stop exactly on 100millionth row, it will grow further.

Comment: @Helio you don't have to generate them, the database does that for you. If you expect more then int capacity you can use bigint instead of int. In over a decade of working with sql server, I've never encountered a situation where a guid would be a better surrogate key then an int.

Comment: @ZoharPeled database does use cpu generating integer or uniqueidentifier, and it is harder FOR DATABASE to generate 100millionth integer identity than generate 100millionth uniqueidentifier identity.

Comment: @Helio perhaps. but it's easier to index, store and search them. normally when people talk about performance they mean performance of select statements, rarely it's performance of insert statements that matters the most...